# Как подключиться к веб-камере удаленного пользователя?

Tags: javascript, html5

Привет, All!

Как подключиться к веб-камере удаленного пользователя, если у меня веб-камера не установлена?

Юзаю webRTC, но у меня не срабатывает событие onaddstream.
Возможно ли на этой технологии реализовать подобную веб-трансляцию или это в принципе не возможно?
(Все встреченные решения для веба требуют установленной камеры.)

Comment: @ravend, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Недавно нашел, положил в закладки: https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/js/
Библиотека на js.